# Vertical flipped line exported as SVG shows coords "flipped"?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I have a line created in Illustrator. This line have some small curves. Im animating (revealing) this line with an animation library.

My issue is: In Illustrator I flipped the line vertical and when exporting the line as SVG, this seems to result in paths coordinates that relates to the "un-flipped" line - meaning, the coordinates for the line starts (is created) from bottom and up.

I need the coordinates for the path to start from the top. Any ideas?

In any case the SVG output could be of use, then it's:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   width="30px" height="1072px" viewBox="0 0 30 1072" enable-background="new 0 0 30 1072" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M17.251,1071.98V745.314v1c0.667-10-16-51.658-16-75.299
  c0-87,24-54,24-219.999c0-15.092,0-29.522,0-43.286c-24.837-11.71,2.13-3.346,0-39.291c-25.999,27.605,15.283-33.305,0-35.269
  c-20.579-6.855,2.564-30.182,0-31.223c0-9.729,0-18.778,0-27.146V0.016"/>
</svg>
```